# Http request - IMG vs TEXT?

Tags: javascript, http, image, httprequest

The timeline shown here (captured using IE’s F12 developer tools) illustrates how IE handles a page
where an `<img>` tag is located **after** of a bunch of `text` :

[image]

The second row shows the retrieval of the image. Since the image is small, all of the image data is included with the HTTP response headers in the same packet.

However - The next timeline shows what happens when the `<img>` tag is located **close to** the beginning of the file so that it’s in the first packet of data received by IE:

[image]

However, the request for the image starts shortly after the first packet of HTML arrives.

As a result, it takes **less total time** to retrieve the page and the image

But (IMHO) it is better to put images (with defined dimensions) on the bottom of that page. ( so that the page will load faster)

However - by my example it shows that the page is loading faster when the img is on top.

What am I missing ?

*P.S. my question is a briefly summarized text **[of this section](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=fCK3MMV8iYcC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22As%20a%20result,%20it%20takes%20less%20total%20time%20to%20retrieve%20the%20page%20and%20the%20image.%22&source=bl&ots=F5E-afIawo&sig=SOFpy0mB8HbByIkox61aUKpwDGE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TYDRULjADsO40QX5nYGYCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22As%20a%20result,%20it%20takes%20less%20total%20time%20to%20retrieve%20the%20page%20and%20the%20image.%22&f=false)***

Comment: "*... But the best practices always says to put images (with defined dimensions) on the bottom of that page...*," Who? Reference needed

Comment: @Alexander ( added IMHO) , but the dimensions should be there (100%). still  , why the overall time is changing ?. please look at the link ive supplied.

Comment: The browser can't start downloading an image until it has its URL, so the sooner you provide the URL, the better. Browsers use strategies called Lookahead to identify resources to download (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/ie8-lookahead-downloader-fixed.aspx). Why is this post tagged with "Fiddler"? If you had Fiddler running, you must ensure that Streaming is enabled (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp).

Comment: @EricLaw Thanks. it is indeed isnt related to fiddler. fixing.... PS does it mean that I should put the images at top ? (so that they wil have the url as soon as possible ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing several points.
First, the best practices are not only about downloading, but about rendering as well, because if the whole page is downloaded for 3s but in require another 2s to be rendered, the user waits 5s, not 3s. I don't know best practice for putting images at the bottom (there is such for scripts), the best practice I know is to include width and height attributes so you do not block rendering while the image is being downloaded.

Another thing you are missing in your test is parallel downloading, as browsers limit the number of concurrent connections and you are testing with only one image. Make your tests with more images, or best - with a real web page, in order to have reliable results.

Comment: your section is irrelevant since currently there is 6 concurrent connection limitation  and my example discuss about only 2. I don't have a problem of "missing connections to handle all request"/

Comment: My point is that best practices are not written for your specific case, but for general cases, where there are more than 6 resources to load

Comment: Still , why the second example loads in less time ? what is the difference between IMG text vs text IMG  ?

Comment: Just a guess: in case img,text, browser receives the img tag, parse it while it receives the text, and starts request for the img before it finished parsing text. In the text,img, it first receives the html, then parse it, and the downloading of img starts latter. So it is case with parallel requests - in the first case (img,text) there is no delay before starting the second download thread

Comment: Does it have to download the entire html to begin parsing ?

Comment: If it download the entire html to begin parsing, there would not be difference. The difference is if the img is in the beginning, it is parsed earlier, and downloading starts earlier; it is in the end, it is parsed later, and download beginning later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather bother about lessing number of connections, - loading whole page at once. Split interface and content parts. Once interface loaded - it can ask user to wait and inform him about connection speed. Then put a progress bar and inform user about how things go.